# Logins still associated even after removing one

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I appear to have got myself into a mess regarding logins.

My problems started because I wanted to keep my professional and personal accounts separate, now that I'm looking for jobs through Stack Overflow.

So on following the advice found in several posts about keeping professional and personal accounts separate, I simply created a new account with a different email address on writers.stackexhange.com.

Both logins used the Stack Exchange OpenID.

So far so good.

Then I thought it would be great if I could reassign my SciFi account created with my professional login to my personal login.

So again, on reading a few more posts on meta I thought I had a handle on it, so I added my personal login to my professional one in the belief that I could then delete my professional login from my SciFi account, leaving it just with the personal one.

But then I realised it doesn't work like that; the logins are for all sites in the network. Ooops. Delete a login while on one site and that login is deleted for all sites.

OK, I thought, then I'll just remove my personal login and start all over again. I'm not bothered about what little rep I had on Writers and SciFi.

However, after deleting my personal login, and logging out of all sites, and using a browser I hadn't used before (to avoid cookies), when I logged in with my personal account it went through the process that made it seem it's a new login, but I end being associated with all the sites of my professional login again.

I'm guessing somewhere in the background the two logins are still associated.

I also note that most of the posts I read on the matter of keeping professional and personal accounts separate are several years old.

What I would like to know is:

1. Can my personal login be just associated with Writers and SciFi, and any association with my professional login be removed?
2. Failing 1, can my personal login to be totally deleted along with any association with my professional login so I can just start again with my personal login?

I'm guessing that both these options would require some manual intervention from the good folk at Stack Exchange (I have already contacted them with this problem).

Are there any other options available whereby I can remove all associations between my professional and my personal logins?

Or could this be a timing issue? If I delete my personal login, then try again much later, might that approach solve my problem? (Yeah, I know, why don't I try it, but how long is 'much later'? An hour? A day? A week?)

If this is not possible, then I guess I'll have to delete my personal login, delete my profiles for Writers and SciFi, and sign up with a totally new email.

Comment: There is one network account that is linked to the user profile on each site.  If you want to operate under two separate accounts you need to use two browsers or at least two separate browser sessions (one normal, one in private mode will work). Once the accounts are merged you are out of luck I guess. But that needs SE staff to confirm.

Comment: Can you email me (address is in my profile)? Specifically, I'm interested in which email credential is your personal one and which is the work one. I can dig into what happened here and whether there's anything we can do to separate things out for you.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. :) The message you sent in to our support team got assigned to me earlier today. I'll take a look at it tomorrow (Friday) and see what we can do.

Comment: Handling this through our support channels, so gonna close the question.